# Rust and jsonwebtoken: unable to validate a RSA signed jwt token

Tags: rust, jwt, openssl, rust-axum

Acutally playing with rust and jwt, I am developing a dummy app that basically does two things: return a jwt token when user does login (it relies on github as idp),

```
...
let claim = Claims {
  user_email: String::from(user_email.as_str()),
  auth_provider: String::from("github"),
  token: cookie_value.clone() //it is a String too
};
let token = sign_with_key(private_key, claim).unwrap();

return (
  StatusCode::OK,
  [(header::SET_COOKIE, token)],
  Json(json!({
    "user": user_email
  }))
);
...
fn sign_with_key(private_key: String, user_claims: Claims) -> Result<String, String> {
  println!("private_key: {}", private_key);
  let encoding_key = EncodingKey::from_rsa_pem(private_key.as_bytes()).unwrap();
  let token = encode(&Header::new(Algorithm::RS256), &user_claims,&encoding_key).unwrap();
  return Ok(token);
}
```

and verify the token stored in the cookie,

```
pub async fn verify(Extension(public_key): Extension<String>, headers: HeaderMap) -> impl IntoResponse {
  let cookie = headers.get("cookie");
  let decoding_key = DecodingKey::from_rsa_pem(public_key.as_bytes()).unwrap();
  println!("cookie {:?}, {}", cookie, &cookie.unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
  match decode::<Claims>(&cookie.unwrap().to_str().unwrap(), &decoding_key, &Validation::new(Algorithm::RS256)) {
    Ok(token_data) => {
      println!("token inner user_email {:?}", token_data.claims.user_email);
      return StatusCode::OK;
    },
    Err(e) => {
      println!("ERROR: {:?}", e);
      return StatusCode::UNAUTHORIZED;
    }
  }
}
```

`private_key` and `public_key` are respectively obtained by the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out keymaster.private.pem 2048
openssl rsa -in keymaster.private.pem -pubout > keymaster.public.pem
```

I was expecting that the token I got by running the first code to be positively verified by the `verify` function but I am getting an `InvalidSignature` error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot reproduce with my own MRE. However, based on the `Claims` type you have provided, you should get an error that it is missing an `exp` field during verification. When I add this, it works. I strongly suspect that `headers.get("cookie")` is incorrect here, as you don't actually parse the header -- and there can be more than one, as well. You probably want to extract a `TypedHeader<Cookie>`. `[(header::SET_COOKIE, token)]` is also likely incorrect as it's missing the cookie name, for example.